Linphone mave repository not found
I've been using linphone sdk for a while for my android app, today suddenly I'm getting the following error:

Could not find any matches for org.linphone:linphone-sdk-android:5.3+
as no versions of org.linphone:linphone-sdk-android are available.
Required by:
project :app

SO i went online and searched for "https://linphone.org/maven_repository/" and I'm getting Not found!

Is there some issue with linphone server?

Sorry about that, we are migrating our website and it broke the redirection.
We'll fix it asap, in the meantime you can change the repo URL to https://download.linphone.org/maven_repository/

Thank you! have changed the link and its working!
